# How to generate encrypted cartid to access the Rest API guest cart - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I get quote id from below code it returns 6 as my quote id

```
$id=$this->_checkoutSession->getQuoteId();
```

I used the quote_id=6 in REST api like `rest/default/V1/guest-carts/6/estimate-shipping-methods`

It throws the below error in Postman

`{
    "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "cartId",
        "fieldValue": 0
    }
}`

I have checked frontend cart page actual cart id seems encrypted `rest/default/V1/guest-carts/6vf0uVP3A3RNBbTDPe4ECKxjDrJw44lO/estimate-shipping-methods`

could you please anyone enlighten me? Thanks.

syntax

rest/default/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/estimate-shipping-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the checkout session you can able to find the masked quote in js itself.

`window.checkoutConfig.quoteData.entity_id` for guest user.

**For Examle**

if `window.checkoutConfig.quoteData.entity_id` is digit means

```
  `customer is logged in`
```

else

```
  `guest session` there you can find the masked quote id
```

**For generating the Masked Quote id**

inject the  `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory`

`$quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load(YOUR_QUOTE_ID, 'quote_id');
$id = $quoteIdMask->getMaskedId();`